# Swift 2.0 - Can't figure out how to add Sounds to a Game

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio

I am trying to add audio to my game and just cannot figure out how. There are tons of tutorials on how to add sound for Swift but not Swift 2.0. All I am trying to do is have sound effects when I tap the screen.

I've seen some people say to use "init" but I cannot get that to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some more specifics about what you have tried?

Comment: I've testing AVAudioPlayer in a couple of ways: One - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786877/avaudioplayer-no-longer-working-in-swift-2-0-xcode-7-beta/ Two - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaFvJajJo8k/ Three - https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/38zgvr/avaudioplayer_is_not_playing_sound/

Comment: Some code looked like this: var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("coin", ofType: "wav")) ///  audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: nil) ///

Comment: With Swift 2.0 (error: nil) does not work anymore. Also when using init I keep running into problems. Thanks.